# Bottle of beer program breaks after interpolation

Tags: c#, while-loop, interpolation

I was just trying to interpolate in an effort to clean up my code and it breaks my program. I'm needing help understanding why it breaks. After the change, the decrements stop. Original code is just type out on every if(). Original code before change is at the bottom. The top code with run, just no longer decrements from 99.

```
        int bottlesOfBeer = 99;
        string verse1 = $"{bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall, {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer.";
        string verse2 = $"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall";
        string singleVerse1 = $"{bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall, {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer.";
        string singleVerse2 = $"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall";
        while (bottlesOfBeer > 0)
        {
            if (bottlesOfBeer >= 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(verse1);
                bottlesOfBeer--;
                if (bottlesOfBeer == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(singleVerse2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(verse2);
                }
            }          
            else if (bottlesOfBeer == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(singleVerse1);
                bottlesOfBeer--;
                if (bottlesOfBeer == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(verse1);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Check the back cause we need more");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(singleVerse2);
                }**

     int bottlesOfBeer = 99;

        string verse1 = $"{bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall, {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer.";
        string verse2 = $"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall";
        string singleVerse1 = $"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall";
        string singleVerse2 = $"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall";


        while (bottlesOfBeer > 0)
        {
            if (bottlesOfBeer >= 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall, {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer.");
                bottlesOfBeer--;
                if (bottlesOfBeer == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall");
                }
            }          
            else if (bottlesOfBeer == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall, {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer.");
                bottlesOfBeer--;
                if (bottlesOfBeer == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer on the wall, {bottlesOfBeer} bottles of beer.");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Check the back cause we need more");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Take one down, pass it around {bottlesOfBeer} bottle of beer on the wall");
                }
```

Comment: "After the change, the decrements stop. " Which change? Could you please add some more debugging-details?

Comment: Because the variable _bottleOfBeer_ is evaluated just one time at the moment where you build the string. It doesn't change the string if the variable changes

Comment: so you need to print the string on every iteration.

Comment: Move interpolated strings inside the loop, use `string.Format` with predefined string parameter containing `{0}`, define those strings inside `Func<int, string>` delegates, use methods/local methods.